# Connect enums with select2 list

Tags: laravel, forms, enums, jquery-select2

I have a create and edit form for my datatable and I have a dropdown that
[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paDAY.png)

I created the drop-down manually like so:

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
  <option value="1">COM01</option>
  <option value="2">COM02</option>
  <option value="3">COM03</option>
  <option value="4">COM04</option>
  <option value="5">COM05</option>
  <option value="6">COM06</option>
  <option value="7">COM07</option>
  <option value="8">COM08</option>
  <option value="9">COM09</option>
</select>
```

However, I am using the [Laravel Enums library by bensampo](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum) and I want to use that to generate the select list. I have this class in a .php file called

> MailMessageType

```
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;

/**
 * @method static static COM01()
 * @method static static COM02()
 * @method static static COM03()
 * @method static static COM04()
 * @method static static COM05()
 * @method static static COM06()
 * @method static static COM07()
 * @method static static COM08()
 * @method static static COM09()
 * @method static static OptionOne()
 * @method static static OptionTwo()
 * @method static static OptionThree()
 */
    final class MailMessageType extends Enum {
        const COM01 =   0;
        const COM02 =   2;
        const COM03 =   3;
        const COM04 =   4;
        const COM05 =   5;
        const COM06 =   6;
        const COM07 =   7;
        const COM08 =   8;
        const COM09 =   9; }
```

I have to use this Enum class with my create and edit tables (like my first image) and I need send as number to my form **with a select2 plugin script, not a simple selector**

How could I do it?

many thanks :D

Comment: Not sure what if you're asking anything more complex, but you can simply keep the select list as is and call `$('#type').select2();` in JavaScript to make it a select2 dropdown

Comment: @JasonRoman thanks for reply, but I'm triying to do that with enums, I don't want to have that list done manually

It's possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to auto-generate the list rather than do it manually?

Comment: @JasonRoman I have a file called MailMessageType.php with ENUMS by bensampo  final class MailMessageType extends Enum

I need to fill the list with those enums, not the one I did manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the enums as a key/value array. If you look at the [library on GitHub](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum)
you will see two functions that do this, [`static asArray(): array`](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum#static-asarray-array) and [`static asSelectArray(): array`](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum#static-asselectarray-array). In your case to get the array to populate your select you would call:

```
// returns [0 => 'COM01', 1 => 'COM02', 2 => 'COM03', ...]
MailMessageType::asSelectArray()
```

You would pass it to your template in some fashion like so:

```
return view('my.view', [
    // ...
    'mailMessageTypes' => MailMessageType::asSelectArray(),
]);
```

Then you can loop through it in your template:

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
@foreach ($mailMessageTypes as $value => $label)
    <option value="{{ $value }}">
        {{ $label }}
    </option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Then just initialize the select2 instance:

```
$('#type').select2();
```

**UPDATE**

The `asSelectArray()` function assumes version 3.3.0 of the enum library, but for version 2.x the function is `toSelectArray()`.

Also, the library uses a static function called [`getFriendlyKeyName()`](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum/blob/cac90ee1fa93c605e7a9d12ee51f90ea12c5e95f/src/Enum.php#L434) to convert the key to a string. In this case it thinks a capital letter is a new word and puts a space between each, hence getting `C o m01`. However it provides a [Localization](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum/tree/v3.0.0#localization) feature which allows you to [specify how the strings should be converted](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum/tree/v3.0.0#enum-descriptions). In your case you would make a file like so:

```
// resources/lang/en/enums.php
<?php

use App\Enums\MailMessageType;

return [
    MailMessageType::class => [
        MailMessageType::COM01 => 'COM01',
        MailMessageType::COM02 => 'COM02',
        MailMessageType::COM03 => 'COM03',
        MailMessageType::COM04 => 'COM04',
        MailMessageType::COM05 => 'COM05',
        MailMessageType::COM06 => 'COM06',
        MailMessageType::COM07 => 'COM07',
        MailMessageType::COM08 => 'COM08',
        MailMessageType::COM09 => 'COM09',
    ],
];
```

This translation takes precedence and should give you properly converted strings. You will also have to extend your enum class properly:

```
use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;
use BenSampo\Enum\Contracts\LocalizedEnum;

final class MailMessageType extends Enum implements LocalizedEnum
{
    // ...
}
```

If you don't want to use localizations you can individually [override the `getDescription()` method](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum/tree/v3.0.0#overriding-the-getdescription-method).

Comment: thanks a lot!! but my enum version is old, I just have "toselectarray", it's ok,
it works, but the options appear to me as "C o m01"

Comment: I will update my answer accordingly, that's because of the way the Enum library translates the values

Comment: Updated my answer to explain why the options appear that way and to also point out the older version function `toSelectArray()`

Comment: Many thanks!! finally I override the getDescription() with

    public static function getDescription($value): string
    {
        return 'COM0' . $value;
        return parent::getDescription($value); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }

Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you got it to work and were able to use the enum library's own functions to help you properly generate the drop-down lists.

Comment: excuse me, I tried to view my selection on a "show" view, How can I get a type value from the database to see what I entered?

Comment: The documentation I linked for the enum library has all the info you need, should be the `getDescription()` function, which you have already overridden and should be familiar with